# What does the "record too long" error mean in Stata?

Tags: stata

I'm converting a large dataset of birth certificate information from a raw DAT file to Stata DTA.  I have a data dictionary prepared by the National Bureau of Economic Research, and I have successfully input similar files from other years.

However, when I run the input program on this particular file, I receive the error

> record too long

The output dataset is missing ~14% of the records.  There is more than enough space on disk for the output. What could this seemingly paradoxical error mean?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post this and answer it, merely because I was able to find little online documentation about this Stata error.

In my case, it was actually an easy fix.  The raw data originated in a zip file.  When I unarchived the raw data once more, I found that the original file was about 1GB larger than the raw file I had been working with - there was the missing 14%.  Whatever unzipping error caused the truncation also probably truncated mid-record, and thus Stata produced the "record too long" error when I ran the input program.